# Blazor client side Get Request

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

I'm trying to get an IEnumerable from a data repository from a localhost server api in the client Blazor application using a GET request.

Postman returns the expected result when the server is queried. (https://localhost:44326/api/work)

However my Blazor application keeps evaluating a null response. What am I doing wrong?

```
@page "/showcase"
@inject HttpClient httpClient

<section class="color3 background-1">
    @if (Works == null)
    {
        <p class="text-md-center"><em>Finding Work Examples...</em></p>
    }
    else
    {
        @foreach (var works in Works)
        {
            <article class="background color1">
                <img />
                <h3>@works.Name</h3>
                <p> @works.Text </p>
                <span>
                    <a href="@works.ProjectPath">
                        Go To Demo
                    </a>
                    <a href="@works.GitHubPath">
                        Go to Github
                    </a>
                </span>
            </article>
        }

    }
</section>


@functions {
    IEnumerable<MyWorkModel> Works;
    string baseUrl =  "https://localhost:44326";
    
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await load();
    }

    protected async Task load()
    {
        Works = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<IEnumerable<MyWorkModel>>($"{baseUrl}/api/work");
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Thanks for the help everyone.

The issue was with the Json serializer which wasn't happy with the implementation. I switched to the Newtonsoft serialiser and it now works. changes to above:

```
protected async Task load()
    {
        var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync($"{baseUrl}/api/work");
        Works = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<MyWorkModel>>(await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        StateHasChanged();
}
```

Comment: What the browser network log says ?

Comment: The browser network tab shows the correct data is being sent to the client? If so, ensure your property has a public `{ set; }` on it. If that isn't the cause, then try changing it from an `IEnumerable<T>` to an array `T[]`

Comment: When you say it is evaluating a null response do you mean you checked and Works is null after the call or are you assuming that because the data does not display on the page? If you are assuming, try putting a call to `StateHasChanged() ` in the method `load` - after the api call.

Comment: If the response is truly not being de-serialised into Works it's probably because your data (the json) is not compatible with your class MyWorkModel OR it's not compatible with System.Text.Json - if that is the case you can either wrangle the json until it works with STJ or switch to Newtonsoft JSON, which is more forgiving but slower.

Comment: @aguafrommars My network log was having some issue when I reloaded it. I managed to fix the issue with a rebuild of the project. It's showing a 200 response for work. Which is confirmed by Postman with the expected result. Its still not returning any results.

Comment: Also thanks all of you for help.
@MisterMagoo your right it's a de-serialisation error. I'll switch to Newtonsoft JSON.